# iScroll 5 scrolling horizontally iOS

Tags: ios, scroll, iscroll

I'm using iscroll 5 and I have this problem. My iOs app has a scroll horizontal view with a lot of web views. I used iScroll 5 to navigate between pages in the vertical but when I scroll horizontally it's not working because iScroll stop the native horizontal scroll. 
Can someone help me please?
Thanks a lot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to rotate your scrollview in viewDidLoad,

```
self.scrollview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Comment: If I delete iScroll it's work. The problem it's iScroll because it block my app horizontal scroll. I search a method to exclude iScroll when I scroll horizontally.

Comment: Why don't you enable/use horizontal swipe/scroll with iScroll too? I mean in this case horizontal and vertical scrolling could be handled with iScroll.